# How can I root a Samsung Galaxy Ch@t B5330?

Tags: root-access, samsung

I could find no working (but one not working and one based on very old Android version) root package (nor a custom ROM like Cyanogenmod support) for my Android smartphone (Samsung Galaxy Ch@at B-5330) but I need it desperately. I have general Java programming and Linux administration skills. Can I do the trick myself? How do the root ROMs authors do it? I know how to reset the root password on a normal Linux PC but have no idea of how to do it on a phone.

Comment: xda-developers has several guides on rooting this device, have you checked their forums ?

Comment: Yes, @svarog, I have tried the roms published there with no luck (4.1.2 version hangs "flashing" for hours until the battery gets depleted and changes nothing and another one is Android 2.2 or 2.3 which is just too obsolete to consider)